# Smith normal form and gcd?

Tags: matrices, gcd-and-lcm, smith-normal-form

I am trying to understand how to reduce different matrices to Smith normal form. I have tried to read online and in our textbook, but I do not quite understand the explanations and general proofs. In particular I wonder how **gcd** correlates to finding Smith normal form.

I have done quite a few exercises and can normal get the the correct diagonal matrix through just row and column operations, but it would be nice to understand the concept and the correlation to gcd better. Hopefully someone has a good understanding of this they would like to share.

In advance; thank you :)

Comment: This idea comes up in control theory, specifically in realization theory. I am not sure of your background, but you could check out how the Smith normal form is used there(Reference: A Linear Systems Primer by Panos J. Antsaklis).

Comment: The class is mostly over rings, ideals and modules, but the last section of the class is purely matrices over different rings (ie. polynomial, PID, etc.). Thank you for the anwser :) @psitama

Comment: well, find the Smith form for $$  \left( \begin{array}{cc} 105 & 42 \\ 70 &30 \end{array} \right)  $$   and relate that to $\gcd(105, 42,70,30)$